# Adjusting opacity and updating the properties of a text object in a canvas in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, opacity

I created a canvas and inside I put an image. I also can change the properties of the watermark text and would like to update the text on the canvas when I make some changes.
I created the text inside of the canvas with create_text and when I initialize the program, I  created a variable. text_variable = canvas.create_text(...) However, I couldn't also adjust the opacity of the text.

**Problems:**

- I can't adjust the opacity
- I can't update color, font style, font size and position after I put this text on the canvas.

**I expect:**

- Change the text when I change some properties from the edit menu
- Add opacity adjustment to the text

[image]

```
self.watermark_display = self.display_canvas.create_text(self.watermark_start_position_x, self.watermark_start_position_y, text="Plese write your watermark!", font=(self.fonttype.get(),self.fontsize.get()),fill=self.color_choice)
```

```
def update_watermark_display(self):
    self.display_canvas.itemconfig(self.watermark_display, self.watermark_start_position_x, self.watermark_start_position_y, text="Plese write your watermark!", font=(self.fonttype.get(),self.fontsize.get()),fill=self.color_choice)
```

When I try to do with this way, I got Type Error.

> ```
> self.display_canvas.itemconfig(self.watermark_display, self.watermark_start_position_x, self.watermark_start_position_y, text="Plese write your watermark!", font=(self.fonttype.get(),self.fontsize.get()),fill=self.color_choice)
> ```

TypeError: Canvas.itemconfigure() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: I think yes because in this position the code is not important. It was too long. Therefore, I didn't want to paste all code here. I ask a more theoretical question than a code help. I am also a beginner and do this for fun so I don't know how a question really should be. I read hints next to create a question screen and created accordingly to this.

Comment: Use `create_text(..., anchor='NW'...)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @module_art. I am asking this question because the whole day, I searched online and couldn't what I needed.

Comment: You can't pass x/y coordinates via `itemconfig`

Comment: @Thingamabobs I need a specific coordinate adjustment on the canvas. The anchor doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley How can I do this else than itemconfig?

Comment: use the `coords` method

Comment: @Bryan Oakley OK. I use coords for positioning then how can I change font size, font type, color, and especially opacity. I can't change opacity of the text.

Comment: @Elentronics you can use `canvas.coords(x,y)` or `canvas.move(+x,-y)` which seems more what you want. Opacity of text is not natively supported, but I would recommend `pillow` eitherway. You may want to use a brand label as well and pictures will lead to more satisfying results.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `itemconfig` to change the coordinates. Instead, use the `coords` method for the coordinates, and `itemconfig` for the item configuration.

```
self.display_canvas.itemconfig(
    self.watermark_display, 
    text="Plese write your watermark!", 
    font=(self.fonttype.get(),self.fontsize.get()),
    fill=self.color_choice
)
self.display_canvas.coords(
    self.watermark_display, 
    self.watermark_start_position_x, 
    self.watermark_start_position_y
)
```

Comment: How about opacity? I definitely need to adjust the opacity of the text. Is there any way to change the opacity?

Comment: @Elentronics: canvas items don't support opacity, though you can simulate it to a limited degree with the stipple attributes.

Comment: @Elentronics You can add the watermark to an image using something like [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and then show it using `tkinter`. I am pretty sure PIL supports text opacity.

Comment: I have never heard of stipple attributes. I am going to check it, How about using Label? Can I give any opacity with Label?